Canvas app classic combo box shows looks double
In a Canvas app, I have a classic combo box (not modern) that is bind to a sharepoint list of people column and it is a classic (not modern combo box).
The combo box looks like this (like double) whenever I want to search.
What can I do to resolve this?

Thank you

It looks like you added more than one box there. Did you check in Power Apps?
